# Will the mass of ethene change if it is polymerized into poly ethene?

Tags: polymers

Choose the correct answer  and give a reason :
When the ethene is polymerized into poly ethene , all coming will change except (mass- molar mass- density )

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax.This appears to be a [homework question](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/), please share your thoughts and attempts towards the solution. If you receive useful answers, consider [accepting](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) one.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Mass of reaction mixture doesn't change, because of law of conservation but overall density of polyethene is higher than that of ethene, molar mass too.

Comment: Why won't the mass of the ethene change ?? Poly ethene consists of thousands of ethene moleclues ??